# Android 12- Material You theme not working in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-12

I have created an android 12 emulator to see one of the features that is `material you theme`

Emulator details are

> Name: Pixel 5
>
> CPU: x86_64

the issue is when I change the wallpaper from `settings -> wallpaper & style`, wallpaper changed but the theme according to the wallpaper color is not applied

So my question is

Is Material You supported in the emulator if yes, then how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think it's not supported on Emulator yet.

Answer (score 5):

you can test material you using an emulator by creating one with the Sv2 system image. [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO3Ua.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30211591)

Answer (score 4):

While Material 3 is working on A**ndroid 12** powerd **physical devices**

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features

If you want to test dynamic colors on an Emulator, you need to use an **Android 12L** powered *emulator*.

This is an issue with Android Emulator system image based on API level 31.

In order to install API Level 32 (Android 12L) you can follow this link:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/12L/get#set-up-avd

The image is now called `API 32`:

[image]

See how dynamic colors shows on API 32 eumlator (sx) and not on API 31 one (dx):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the dynamicLightColorScheme in MaterialTheme

Checkout my sample in how to implement:
https://github.com/warting/android-material-you-sample-app/blob/0cd580996ab9468c20c89d10629ae5fc887de398/app/src/main/java/se/warting/examplematerialyou/MainActivity.kt#L65